# How to clear map without using leaflet layer?

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, leaflet, layer

How can i clear map without using leaflet layer?

[image]

Comment: Hi, to help people answer, can you please add a simplified example of what you've tried so far and what result you got

Answer (score 0):

Get your map, and then call:

`map.removeLayer(yourGeoJSON);`

as `yourGeoJSON` is the variable name for the geoJSON you want to remove. I usually keep track of what I add in an array.